# How to convert this QueryString to a JS Object? [NODEJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following querystring which is a IPN by wirecard, so i can't modify this input, this is what i receive in the POST.

I have no clue why is this being sent as text/plain instead of application/json

https://doc.wirecard.com/GeneralPlatformFeatures.html#GeneralPlatformFeatures_IPN

```
response-signature-base64=sGwuDEpTnTB7XwzPga8DG+pYYjB3bga7YOZI8n26yOns=&response-signature-algorithm=HmacSHA256&response-base64=eyJwYXltZW50Ijp7InN0YXR1c2VzIjp7InN0YXR1cyI6W3siY29kZSI6Ij
IwMS4wMDAwIiwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiIzZC1hY3F1aXJlcjpUaGUgcmVzb3VyY2Ugd2FzIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSBjcmVhdGVkLiIsInNldmVyaXR5IjoiaW5mb3JtYXRpb24ifV19LCJjYXJkIjp7ImV4cGlyYXRpb24tbW9udGgiOjEsImV4cGl
yYXRpb24teWVhciI6MjAyMywiY2FyZC10eXBlIjoidmlzYSJ9LCJkZXNjcmlwdG9yIjoiIiwibm90aWZpY2F0aW9ucyI6eyJub3RpZmljYXRpb24iOlt7InVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vNDY0Yjk4N2M2ZDk5Lm5ncm9rLmlvL3B1YmxpY3Mvd2lyZWNh
cmQyIn1dLCJmb3JtYXQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9qc29uLXNpZ25lZCJ9LCJtZXJjaGFudC1hY2NvdW50LWlkIjp7InZhbHVlIjoiN2E2ZGQ3NGYtMDZhYi00ZjNmLWE4NjQtYWRjNTI2ODcyNzBhIn0sInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLWlkIjoiOTQwNGIxN
jQtMTgzYy00ZjllLThmNGEtN2QzMGUxODA2ZWRjIiwicmVxdWVzdC1pZCI6Ijk3NzJiMzViLTdmYmUtNGYxZS04NmQ5LThhNjMwZDljZDg3YyIsInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLXR5cGUiOiJwdXJjaGFzZSIsInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLXN0YXRlIjoic3VjY2
VzcyIsImNvbXBsZXRpb24tdGltZS1zdGFtcCI6MTU5NTkyNDA0OTAwMCwicmVxdWVzdGVkLWFtb3VudCI6eyJ2YWx1ZSI6MTAsImN1cnJlbmN5IjoiVVNEIn0sImFjY291bnQtaG9sZGVyIjp7ImZpcnN0LW5hbWUiOiJkIiwibGFzdC1uYW1lIjo
iZCJ9LCJjYXJkLXRva2VuIjp7InRva2VuLWlkIjoiNDI0Mjc5NjQ0NDA5MDAxOCIsIm1hc2tlZC1hY2NvdW50LW51bWJlciI6IjQyMDAwMCoqKioqKjAwMTgifSwicGF5bWVudC1tZXRob2RzIjp7InBheW1lbnQtbWV0aG9kIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoi
Y3JlZGl0Y2FyZCJ9XX0sImF1dGhvcml6YXRpb24tY29kZSI6IjE0Mzk3NyIsImFwaS1pZCI6IndwcCIsImNhbmNlbC1yZWRpcmVjdC11cmwiOiJodHRwczovL2RlbW9zaG9wLXRlc3Qud2lyZWNhcmQuY29tL2RlbW9zaG9wLyMvY2FuY2VsIiwiZ
mFpbC1yZWRpcmVjdC11cmwiOiJodHRwczovL2RlbW9zaG9wLXRlc3Qud2lyZWNhcmQuY29tL2RlbW9zaG9wLyMvZXJyb3IiLCJzdWNjZXNzLXJlZGlyZWN0LXVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGVtb3Nob3AtdGVzdC53aXJlY2FyZC5jb20vZGVtb3Nob3
AvIy9zdWNjZXNzIiwicHJvdmlkZXItYWNjb3VudC1pZCI6IjcwMDEwIn19
```

As you can see the query parameters are base64 encoded, which is a problem because it includes + and = that are going to break if use URLSearchParams or any other method of converting .

I tried using bodyparser.urlencoded but this transforms '+' to ' '

how can i split this safely while keeping the 3 variables intact

- response-signature-base64
- response-signature-algorithm
- response-base64

Comment: Split it at the `&` first, and then split each part at the first `=` …?

Answer (score 1):

If the [URL Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)  available you could create a URL and read the `searchParams` from it.

If not you can use Javascripts `split()` function using the limit argument:

```
queryString.split('&').map((value) => value.split('=', 2));
```

if an array of arrays is not what you want you can append an other processing step and do something like this:

```
queryString
  .split('&').map((value) => value.split('=', 2))
  .reduce((obj, value) => {
    obj[value[0]] = value[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

the following snippet shows the code in action

```js
  
const queryString = 'response-signature-base64=sGwuDEpTnTB7XwzPga8DG+pYYjB3bga7YOZI8n26yOns=&response-signature-algorithm=HmacSHA256&response-base64=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'

const result = queryString
  .split('&').map((value) => value.split('=', 2))
  .reduce((obj, value) => {
    obj[value[0]] = value[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not work. base64 string sometimes end with "=" with this way, this character dissapears

Comment: well it does because you limit the split operation to two fields. the first occurrence of '=' is the separator between variable name and value

Answer (score 0):

ALMOST, but not quite, using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#Unicode_Strings) code

```js
function fromBinary(binary) {
  console.log(binary.length)
  if (binary.length%2 != 0) binary += "="; // my hack - may not work
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint16Array(bytes.buffer));
};


const str = `response-signature-base64=sGwuDEpTnTB7XwzPga8DG+pYYjB3bga7YOZI8n26yOns=&response-signature-algorithm=HmacSHA256&response-base64=eyJwYXltZW50Ijp7InN0YXR1c2VzIjp7InN0YXR1cyI6W3siY29kZSI6Ij
IwMS4wMDAwIiwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiIzZC1hY3F1aXJlcjpUaGUgcmVzb3VyY2Ugd2FzIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSBjcmVhdGVkLiIsInNldmVyaXR5IjoiaW5mb3JtYXRpb24ifV19LCJjYXJkIjp7ImV4cGlyYXRpb24tbW9udGgiOjEsImV4cGl
yYXRpb24teWVhciI6MjAyMywiY2FyZC10eXBlIjoidmlzYSJ9LCJkZXNjcmlwdG9yIjoiIiwibm90aWZpY2F0aW9ucyI6eyJub3RpZmljYXRpb24iOlt7InVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vNDY0Yjk4N2M2ZDk5Lm5ncm9rLmlvL3B1YmxpY3Mvd2lyZWNh
cmQyIn1dLCJmb3JtYXQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9qc29uLXNpZ25lZCJ9LCJtZXJjaGFudC1hY2NvdW50LWlkIjp7InZhbHVlIjoiN2E2ZGQ3NGYtMDZhYi00ZjNmLWE4NjQtYWRjNTI2ODcyNzBhIn0sInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLWlkIjoiOTQwNGIxN
jQtMTgzYy00ZjllLThmNGEtN2QzMGUxODA2ZWRjIiwicmVxdWVzdC1pZCI6Ijk3NzJiMzViLTdmYmUtNGYxZS04NmQ5LThhNjMwZDljZDg3YyIsInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLXR5cGUiOiJwdXJjaGFzZSIsInRyYW5zYWN0aW9uLXN0YXRlIjoic3VjY2
VzcyIsImNvbXBsZXRpb24tdGltZS1zdGFtcCI6MTU5NTkyNDA0OTAwMCwicmVxdWVzdGVkLWFtb3VudCI6eyJ2YWx1ZSI6MTAsImN1cnJlbmN5IjoiVVNEIn0sImFjY291bnQtaG9sZGVyIjp7ImZpcnN0LW5hbWUiOiJkIiwibGFzdC1uYW1lIjo
iZCJ9LCJjYXJkLXRva2VuIjp7InRva2VuLWlkIjoiNDI0Mjc5NjQ0NDA5MDAxOCIsIm1hc2tlZC1hY2NvdW50LW51bWJlciI6IjQyMDAwMCoqKioqKjAwMTgifSwicGF5bWVudC1tZXRob2RzIjp7InBheW1lbnQtbWV0aG9kIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoi
Y3JlZGl0Y2FyZCJ9XX0sImF1dGhvcml6YXRpb24tY29kZSI6IjE0Mzk3NyIsImFwaS1pZCI6IndwcCIsImNhbmNlbC1yZWRpcmVjdC11cmwiOiJodHRwczovL2RlbW9zaG9wLXRlc3Qud2lyZWNhcmQuY29tL2RlbW9zaG9wLyMvY2FuY2VsIiwiZ
mFpbC1yZWRpcmVjdC11cmwiOiJodHRwczovL2RlbW9zaG9wLXRlc3Qud2lyZWNhcmQuY29tL2RlbW9zaG9wLyMvZXJyb3IiLCJzdWNjZXNzLXJlZGlyZWN0LXVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGVtb3Nob3AtdGVzdC53aXJlY2FyZC5jb20vZGVtb3Nob3
AvIy9zdWNjZXNzIiwicHJvdmlkZXItYWNjb3VudC1pZCI6IjcwMDEwIn19`





console.log([...new URLSearchParams(str).values()].map(val => fromBinary(atob(val))))
```